# Typescript - Check values in one array are present in another

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have the following array. I am using this array to dynamically produce checkboxes on my UI. This is being used to save user config as to what they will be able to see in a nav menu.

```
  accessLevels: any = [
    {
      description: "Properties",
      type: '1',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Equipment",
      type: '2',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Jobs",
      type: '3',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Calender",
      type: '4',
      selected: false
    }
]
```

I am making a call to an API which returns me an array of the users config. So what I will get is an array of the pages and their type like this:

```
    {
      description: "Equipment",
      type: '2'
    },
    {
      description: "Jobs",
      type: '3'
    }
```

In the array returned from the API I am just getting the values that should appear checked on the check boxes so what I want to do is loop through the returned array and check if any of the types match any types in the checkbox array if they do I want to set 'selected' to true. Thus checking the checkbox.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  async loadLandlordConfig(key: string) {

    const result = await this.userService.loadLandlordConfig(key);

    //let accessLevels = [];

    this.selectedApiValues = result[0].accessLevels;

    this.selectedApiValues.forEach((selectedValue)=> {

    });
  }
```

Im not sure how to cross check the values and then change selected to true.

Hope I have made everything clear enough. 
Any questions please ask. All help appreciated.

Comment: How are you matching objects across arrays? Some array items have "value", some have "type".

Comment: @KurtHamilton Apologies I was just typing the arrays into the there and missed that, my mistake. I have adjusted accordingly

Comment: So you're matching on type?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  const accessLevels: any[] = [
    {
      description: 'Properties',
      type: '1',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: 'Equipment',
      type: '2',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: 'Jobs',
      type: '3',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: 'Calender',
      type: '4',
      selected: false
    }];

  const results: any[] = [
    {
      description: 'Equipment',
      type: '2'
    },
    {
      description: 'Jobs',
      type: '3'
    }];

  accessLevels.forEach(accessLevel => {
    accessLevel.selected = results.some(x => x.type === accessLevel.type); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with the following simple example :

```js
let accessLevels = [
    {
      description: "Properties",
      type: '1',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Equipment",
      type: '2',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Jobs",
      type: '3',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Calender",
      value: '4',
      selected: false
    }
]

let api = [
    {
      description: "Equipment",
      type: '2'
    },
    {
      description: "Jobs",
      value: '3'
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < accessLevels.length; i++) {
     accessLevels[i].selected = api.find(e => e.description === accessLevels[i].description) ? true : false;
}

console.log(accessLevels);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you iterate with a `for` instead of a `.forEach` ? Also a `.find` looks preferable in my point of view as it stops and return as soon as it gets a value as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I updated my answer but keep in mind as long as you can solve the problem at hand, for loop is faster than forEach. Solve first, refactor later!

Answer (score 2):

### For small arrays

You can check for the existence within a filter using some:

```js
const intersect = this.array1.filter(a1 => 
  this.array2.some(a2 => a1.type === a2.type));
```

The problem with this is that you are doing multiple loops through array 2.

### For larger arrays

To keep your loops to a constant number, you could create a map of one of your arrays, and check that within a filter of the other array:

```js
const map2 = new Map(this.array2.map(x => [x.type, s]));
const intersect = this.array1.filter(a1 => 
  map.has(a1.type));
```

This adds a little bit of complexity, but is more efficient for all but the simplest cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` collection to have `O(1)` while mapping the second array:

```
const unique = new Map(received.map(s => [s.description, s]));
const result = accessLevels.map(({ description, type})=> 
    ({selected: (unique.get(description) ? true : false), type, description}))
```

An example:

```js
let accessLevels = [
  {
    description: "Properties",
    type: '1',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    description: "Equipment",
    type: '2',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    description: "Jobs",
    type: '3',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    description: "Calender",
    type: '4',
    selected: false
  }
]

const received = [
  {
  description: "Equipment",
  type: '2'
  },
  {
    description: "Jobs",
    value: '3'
  }
];

const unique = new Map(received.map(s => [s.description, s]));
const result = accessLevels.map(({ description, type})=> 
    ({selected: (unique.get(description) ? true : false), type, description}))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code. Here's how it looks like:

```js
async loadLandlordConfig(key: string) {

    const result = await this.userService.loadLandlordConfig(key);

    // assuming there's always a result.
    // ACCESS_LEVELS is the list of your config.
    accessLevels = result[0].accessLevels;
    this.selectedApiValues = ACCESS_LEVELS.map((al: any) => {
      const selected = accessLevels.findIndex(a => a.type === al.type) > -1;
      return { ...al, selected }
    })
  }
```

This will give you with the value

```js
this.selectedApiValues = [
  {
      description: "Properties",
      type: '1',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      description: "Equipment",
      type: '2',
      selected: true
    },
    {
      description: "Jobs",
      type: '3',
      selected: true
    },
    {
      description: "Calender",
      type: '4',
      selected: false
    }
]
```